# Sort the entries by opening and closing time in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am stuck in a problem related to sorting in elastic search. I am developing eCommerce app. I want to sort the data by opening and closing time of merchant's shop. It means that I want to show the merchants which are open at top and merchants which are closed at the end of the list.

Opening and closing time is stored day wise in this format:

```js
business_timing = [
{
    business_hours : {
     end: 86340 
     start: 32400
    } 
    day: "Sunday"
},
{
    business_hours : {
     end: 86340 
     start: 32400
    } 
    day: "Monday"
},
{
    business_hours : {
     end: 86340 
     start: 32400
    } 
    day: "Tuesday"
},
{
    business_hours : {
     end: 86340 
     start: 32400
    } 
    day: "Wednesday"
},
{
    business_hours : {
     end: 86340 
     start: 32400
    } 
    day: "Thursday"
},
{
    business_hours : {
     end: 86340 
     start: 32400
    } 
    day: "Friday"
},
{
    business_hours : {
     end: 86340 
     start: 32400
    } 
    day: "Saturday"
}
]
```

Opening and closing time of the merchant is stored in seconds.

Any help or hint would be very helpful

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index?